# Deploying to web server & github with one command

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-server

I have a web server with a bare repo in the folder `/var/git/mysite.com.git`. My `hooks/post-receive` looks like this:

`#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite.com/public_html git checkout -f`

I run `git push live master`(where `live` is the name of my remote on the production server) and the post-receive executes properly and puts the files where they need to be in the web root. I then have to run `git push origin master` to push a copy to my github(for backup/review). I may do these in the opposite order as it accomplishes the same thing.

Is there anyway to accomplish both of these steps with one command? It would seem like I could just put the second `git push` command in the post-receive or somewhere else(on Github?) push the repo to both remote locations but I have not found a solution to this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following lines to your `~/.gitconfig` file, to achieve this with an alias:

```
[alias]
  push-live = !git push live master && git push origin master
```

Then you can run `git push-live`, to push to both remotes.

Comment: Good idea, it would seem like this kind of need is so common so it is strange that you have to in essence, 'create a hack' to accomplish this

Comment: I put the alias in the repo's .git/config file. This way, I can just copy the line and put it in every repo I need to do this for instead of having a dedicated bash script just for this.

Answer (score 1):

I use for such deployment tasks Jenkins. Its a very good system to run tasks and check your code before deployment.

https://jenkins-ci.org

Another solution is Ansible to run code on your server (on all server) the combination with Jenkins is very good.

http://www.ansible.com/home

Or you can write a simple shell script with contains all your commands and you call it in your hook. But i prefer a deployment system to run some tasks and check my code before it goes to production.

Comment: I will look at these potential solutions and accept your answer if I use either. This may be the only way of going about it. I guess writing a simple shell script really should be able to do it also but I thought there may be a hook in place that could take care of this

Comment: Normally you do a lot of stuff during the deployment something like run your unit tests or check your code against security issues and many more. With Jenkins you can add your Servers and run your commands on all servers or run a unit tests before your deploy on a server.